# Why does this ternary statement return false positives when in shorthand notation?

Tags: c#, boolean, ternary-operator, boolean-expression, short-circuiting

I've been scratching my head on this one, since these statements seem almost identical aside from format - however the shorthand one seems to evaluate differently, and creates false positives by returning true when it shouldn't.

In the below examples, imagine `programRecord.Award = 'Emmy'` and `targetAward = 'Oscar'`

Bad code giving false positives:

```
private bool MatchMe(string programId, string targetAward, string targetLevel, Program programRecord)
{
    var isMatched = programRecord.Status == "Active"
        && string.IsNullOrEmpty(programId) ? true : programRecord.Pid == programId
        && string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetAward) ? true : programRecord.Award == targetAward
        && string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetLevel) ? true : programRecord.Level == targetLevel;
    return isMatched;
}
```

Good code:

```
    private bool MatchMe(string programId, string targetAward, string targetLevel, Program programRecord)
    {
        var isMatched = programRecord.Status == "Active";
        var isMatched2 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(programId) ? true : programRecord.Pid == programId;
        var isMatched3 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetAward) ? true : programRecord.Award == targetAward;
        var isMatched4 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetLevel) ? true : programRecord.Level == targetLevel;
        var doIMatch = isMatched && isMatched2 && isMatched3 && isMatched4;
        return doIMatch;
    }
```

What is occurring in the shorthand version that causes this? I would think the one false value would force the entire statement to return false, however that doesn't occur with the abbreviated version.

Comment: Side note, rather than using ternary operators, you can use `or` logic. `(string.IsNullOrEmpty(programId) || programRecord.Pid == programId)`. Seeing this is an issue with order of operations, doing this method will quickly highlight the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other have shown, you need to surround the ternary expressions in brackets. The reason being is that, `&&` operator has a higher precedence than `?:` operator.

See: [7.2.1 Operator precedence and associativity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa691323(v=vs.85))

Answer (score 3):

Your format is wrong for what you compare. You actually need the parenthesis to force the inline if to be interpreted correctly.

you should have the following instead

```
private bool MatchMe(string programId, string targetAward, string targetLevel, Program programRecord)
{
    var isMatched = programRecord.Status == "Active"
        && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(programId) ? true : programRecord.Pid == programId)
        && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetAward) ? true : programRecord.Award == targetAward)
        && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetLevel) ? true : programRecord.Level == targetLevel);
    return isMatched;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator is not being evaluated as you think it is. Consider the following example:

```
var val = true ? true : false && false ? false : false;
var val2 = (true ? true : false) && (false ? false : false);
Console.WriteLine(val);
Console.WriteLine(val2);
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

So you see, the first expression is evaluated as

```
var val = true ? true : (false && false ? false : false);
```